# Error in reading OSLC response & executing sparql using jena

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, clearquest, oslc

I'm using OSLC V2.0 to get the data from clearquest (as RDF), save it as a ".rdf" file & execute a sparql query over that file using Apache-Jena.

Data from OSLC response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" xmlns:oslc="http://open-services.net/ns/core#"
    xmlns:cq="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/rational/clearquest/1.0/"
    xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:oslc_cm="http://open-services.net/ns/cm#">
    <oslc:ResponseInfo rdf:about="...">
        <dcterms:title>....</dcterms:title>
        <oslc:totalCount>10</oslc:totalCount>
    </oslc:ResponseInfo>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about=".....">
        <cq:user>
         .......
            <cq:vehicle>
                <cq:type>bike</cq:type>
            </cq:vehicle>
            <cq:vehicle>
                <cq:type>car</cq:type>
            </cq:vehicle>
            <cq:vehicle>
               <cq:type>bike</cq:type>
               <cq:type>car</cq:type>
            </cq:vehicle>
          .......
        </cq:user>
        .......
         other user records
        .......
    </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Code Snippet:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(../../oslc_output.rdf);
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
model.read(in,null);
//model.read(in, "RDF/XML"); - this also didn't work
in.close();

Query query = QueryFactory.create(sparqlQuery);
QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
```

When i try to execute SPARQL over this data am getting following error

```
        org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: [line: xxx, col: yyy] {E201} Multiple children of property element
at org.apache.jena.riot.system.ErrorHandlerFactory$ErrorHandlerStd.error(ErrorHandlerFactory.java:128)
at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangRDFXML$ErrorHandlerBridge.error(LangRDFXML.java:232)
at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.impl.ARPSaxErrorHandler.error(ARPSaxErrorHandler.java:37)
at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.impl.XMLHandler.warning(XMLHandler.java:196)
at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.impl.XMLHandler.warning(XMLHandler.java:173)
at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.impl.XMLHandler.warning(XMLHandler.java:168)
at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.impl.ParserSupport.warning(ParserSupport.java:207)
at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.states.Frame.warning(Frame.java:55)
at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.states.WantLiteralValueOrDescription.startElement(WantLiteralValueOrDescription.java:38)
at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.impl.XMLHandler.startElement(XMLHandler.java:111)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNamespaceBinder.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNamespaceBinder.startElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.impl.RDFXMLParser.parse(RDFXMLParser.java:150)
at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.ARP.load(ARP.java:118)
at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangRDFXML.parse(LangRDFXML.java:134)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParserRegistry$ReaderRIOTLang.read(RDFParserRegistry.java:178)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.process(RDFDataMgr.java:859)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:259)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:245)
at org.apache.jena.riot.adapters.RDFReaderRIOT.read(RDFReaderRIOT.java:69)
at org.apache.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.read(ModelCom.java:275)
```

As per the [OSLC V2.0](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/CqOslcV2) If no content type is requested using either the Accept header or rcm.contentType, RDF/XML is returned.

There's something wrong in one of the following
1. RDF/XML esponse from Clearquest
2. Saving it as ".rdf" text
3. Reading the data using apache jena

Couldn't spot where the issue is.. pl help.. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The RDF data is invalid as the exception says. You can see the line and column in which the problem exist.

Comment: Error is in this part <cq:vehicle> <cq:type>bike</cq:type> <cq:type>car</cq:type> </cq:vehicle> where two types car and bike are under same vehicle tag.. but that's output from Clearquest...